# django model not in urls.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to python and django and I want to know the best way to set things up.

I have a model called `OauthProviders` which I set up to encrypt some fields before save in the ModelViewSet (override `perform_create` method). I dont want to create routes (urls) for this model.

Now, if I want to access this model in the code (I can with `OauthProvider.objects.all()` of course), but I have a few questions:

1. how do I enter data to this model NOT in code? If I use the admin portal for it, it doesn't execute my custom perform_create method, so it gets added to the database in plain text
2. What is the best way to decrypt a message if I retrieve data?

EDIT:
I moved the logic from the ModelViewSet to the save() method on the model with the following code:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.credentials = encrypt_message(self.credentials, '<keyhere>')
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This seems to work. Is this good practice? How to do this with the get method?

Comment: 1. why not to move logic to model save() method? if you do it the logic will be executed when you save an item via django admin as well

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: mode the logic from your custom `perform_create` to `OauthProviders.save()`

Comment: which file? In the model OauthProvider and then `def save():`? And how would I retrieve it? (decrypt on get)?

Answer (score 0):

A good way of doing this is using **[django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#signals)**.

Assuming you have:

```py
class OauthProvider(models.Model):
    pass # some fields here
```

In your case you can use either:

- **[pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#signals)** - code that will be executed **before** `OauthProvider` gets saved in the database.
- **[post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#post-save)** - code that will be executed **after** `OauthProvider` gets saved in the database.

It's up to you to decide when exactly you want to execute additional code.

Example with `pre_save`:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class OauthProvider(models.Model):
    pass # some fields here


@receiver(pre_save, sender=OauthProvider)
def oauthprovider_on_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.credentials = encrypt_message(self.credentials, '<keyhere>')
    # no need to call instance.save() in pre_save signal
```

The `pre_save` signal will be executed:

- If you call `obj.save()` programatically.
- If you save the obj through django admin site.
- If you create/update the obj within rest api